# Project running successfully using maven but failing while running with intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, dependency-injection, guice, dropwizard, intellij-14

I am creating a managed object inside App.java (which is the main class of my module). I am using guice library with dropwizard framework and getting this exception only when running with IntelliJ if I run the same code with mvn it works perfectly fine which is weird and beyond my theory. So if someone has experienced something like this or have some theory behind this then please share. feel free to ask any detail.

```
   environment.lifecycle().manage(new Managed() {
        @Override
        public void start() throws Exception {
        }

        @Override
        public void stop() throws Exception {
        }
    });
```

Exception stacktrace:-

```
  Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

        1) Injecting into inner classes is not supported.  Please use a 'static' class (top-level or nested) instead of com.phonepe.growth.App$4.
        at ru.vyarus.dropwizard.guice.module.installer.InstallerModule.bindExtension(InstallerModule.java:191) (via modules: ru.vyarus.dropwizard.guice.module.GuiceSupportModule -> ru.vyarus.dropwizard.guice.module.installer.InstallerModule)

        1 error
        at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:470)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:155)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:99)
        at ru.vyarus.dropwizard.guice.injector.DefaultInjectorFactory.createInjector(DefaultInjectorFactory.java:20)
        at ru.vyarus.dropwizard.guice.GuiceBundle.createInjector(GuiceBundle.java:191)
        at ru.vyarus.dropwizard.guice.GuiceBundle.run(GuiceBundle.java:138)
        at ru.vyarus.dropwizard.guice.GuiceBundle.run(GuiceBundle.java:93)
        at io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap.run(Bootstrap.java:200)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:42)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:85)
        at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:75)
        at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:79)
        at com.phonepe.growth.App.main(App.java:48)
```

Comment: Try re-importing a project from Maven into IDE and re-create it's configuration: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start

Comment: thanks @Andrey I have tried reimporting the project and even clearing .m2 repository(though that shouldn't have any impact). But it didn't worked out.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a bug in guicey classpath scan (`.enableAutoConfig`).

Your application class is covered by a scan and so inner classes are also visible: when you start app from idea "Managed" inner class (created by the compiler for `new Managed() {...}`) is detected and registered as an extension which also means registration in guice context. But guice can't instantiate the inner class and throws an error.

You can enable extra diagnostic messages with `.printLifecyclePhasesDetailed()` (on guice bundle) and see that additional extension is indeed appear when running from idea.

Most certainly, when you run app from maven it builds into jar first and then launched. In this case, classpath scan works a bit differently and doesn't see inner classes (inside jar).. so everything works.

**Please note** that you don't need to instantiate and register managed object (and other common objects) manually: you can simply [declare managed as a separate class](http://xvik.github.io/dropwizard-guicey/4.2.1/installers/managed/) and guicey will find it and properly register (both in guice and dropwizard). This is the [expected way of extensions registrations](http://xvik.github.io/dropwizard-guicey/4.2.1/concepts/#extensions), especially together with classpath scan.

Comment: Thanks a lot @xvik this is indeed the explanation I was expecting for. I will surely refactor my code as you have suggested.